# Having some case sensitive folder names and file names in Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-svn

I have migrated source code from SVN to Bitbucket. After migration, I have cloned the remote repository into locally (Windows OS).

Later I ran command `git status` its showing list of modified files which I didn't modified after clone.

A lot of research I noticed case sensitive folder names and file names are present in Bitbucket  repository.

`Scenario-1 :Folder names: Folder1
                  folder1`

`Scenario-2: Filenames:
                  Filename1
                  fileName1`

I need the both the scenario-1 & 2 files should be present in repository and after clone repository `git status` should not show list of modified files which I didn't modified after clone. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you need both files available, then your repository needs to be case sensitive.

If you're using Windows 10, you can use [`fsutil`](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/) to make an empty case-sensitive directory and then clone directly into that directory (by specifying it on the command line).  You could also use the Windows Subsystem for Linux to clone your repository, in which case it will also be case sensitive.

I'm not aware of any to do this on Windows before Windows 10.  If you can't use Windows 10, then you'll either need to find a way to rename files such that they don't collide in case or use a POSIX-compatible operating system like Linux.

Comment: As mentioned, Enabled `fsutil` to an empty directory and cloned repo into that directory. After clone, I ran command `git status`, Its still showing list of modified files.

Comment: It looks like `fsutil` isn't recursive by default, so you'll probably need to make each folder case-sensitive individually, or use WSL to clone it into your C drive, in which case all the directories it creates will be case sensitive.  If you make them all case sensitive manually, you'll probably need to run `git reset --hard` to get everything checked out properly.

Comment: After ran this command `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` I'm able to run linux commands in `cmd` I have cloned repository into local. After cloning its showing warning message like this `warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree`
`dir1/subdir/Testfile
dir1/subdir/testfile
` 
Later I went to path: `dir1/subdir` and did `ls`.Only one file is `Testfile` available. `testfile` is not available in the directory.

Comment: I ran this command `git reset --hard` as well. But no luck. Still showing modified files.

Comment: @viswa: You have a modern Git that detects case collisions. However, Git thinks that all folders have the same case sensitivity (or lack thereof) so it won't know the right thing about any particular case-sensitive folders. I know nothing about the Windows side of this but the obvious thing to do is to create two different files with only-case-different names *in* the folder, to see if the case-sensitive mode is working. If so, the Git stuff should work even if Git warns you.

Comment: @torek: 1.After enable the `fsutil`, case-sensitive mode is working for specified path only. Changes doesn't apply to the sub-directories. (In our use case, we can't able to enable `fsutil` for each sub-directory )
2. In the specified `fsutil` enabled path, I have created two files `Filename1 and filename1`. I ran command `ls` and I can able to see both the files. 
- Later I tried to add both files to git. command: `git add Filename1 filename1` Only one file 'Filename1` has been staged. Git is not able to track case-sensitive files it seems.

Comment: @viswa: Interesting - this is probably a side effect of having `core.ignorecase` set to `true`. Try `git -c core.ignorecase=false add Filename1 filename1`.

Comment: @torek. Awesome, Now I can able to add case-sensitive files to git. 
Is there any way we can enable `setCaseSensitiveInfo` recursively to all folders and subfolders before cloning repository?

Comment: @viswa I do not have or use Windows; I have no idea whether there is some way to do that.